# Version control for completely local and with restriction?

Tags: version-control

We need one of version control that can use completely local like in local network collaborators connect to one PC and clone or create branch, no code upload to the server or something like that.

1. All collaborators access to the repository in company via local network.
2. Collaborators does not access to repository out of the company.

which source control can we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all version control systems support putting your central repository inside a local network instead of on the internet, including the one mentioned in your question's tag (currently: git, svn). GitLab, for instance, is a package you can install on a machine inside your local network to get a similar experience to the one on gitlab.com, only it's not accessible outside your network.

If you want to avoid having to set up something on a central machine in your network (which is pretty much a requirement if you want to clone from and push to a central place in your network), you'll be wanting to look at *decentralized* systems, such as Git or Mercurial. In these systems, each local checkout/clone is a fully-featured repository and others can fetch from it (provided you're letting them access it via something like SSH).

Most people are much more used to centralized workflows, so if you do have the time and inclination to set up something like GitLab, it's probably easier to explain to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Git is a perfect fit for you.
[Git homepage](https://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use git as Source Control and can install gitlab on your local server. We in our company use Gitlab locally and its very convenient. Moreover, All of your requirement perfectly serve by gitLab. Can download Gitlab-Offline from

https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce